# textpad regex search start of the line & end of the line

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, textpad

I want to find all the lines in .java, .jsp file using Textpad where in

```
start of the line is //
end of the line is ;
```

e.g.

```
// logger.debug("rowData: "+rowData);
```

Can it be done using Regex Match in Text Pad? or do I need to write a Perl Program, Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex with multiline option

```
^\s*//.*?;
```